# How I make AMPM to 24 Hours in Javescript

Tags: javascript

How can I make this : "08:30AM-09:30AM"
into this : "20:30-21:30"
Thank you!
Its Sentence (String Value)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean "08:30PM-09:30PM" into "20:30-21:30"

```js
function to24Hours(time){
    let hours = time.substr(0,2);
    let minutes = time.substr(3,2);
    let AMorPm = time.substr(5,2);

    if(AMorPm ==="PM"){
        let PMhour = parseInt(hours) + 12
        let h = PMhour === 24 ? "12" : String(PMhour)
        return `${h.padStart(0,2)}:${minutes}`
    } 

    let AMhour = hours === "12" ? "00" : hours
    return `${AMhour}:${minutes}`
}

function to24HoursRange(timeRange){
    const [time1, time2] = timeRange.split("-")
    return to24Hours(time1) + "-" + to24Hours(time2)
}

console.log(to24HoursRange("08:30PM-09:30PM"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `moment` library to solve your problem.

You can specify time to the moment constructor and then use the [format](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/01-format/) option.

Example :

```js
const time = "08:30PM-09:30PM"

const times = time.split('-')

const newTimes = times.map(t => moment(t, ["h:mm A"]).format("HH:mm"))

console.log(newTimes.join('-'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```